# MySql, Multiple or different databases? 1 search engine

Tags: mysql, database

I need experts advice for how should I go with database designing?

I'm Making an ecommerce website platform, which will have different ecommerce websites inside it.

1) To simply understand you can say, The parent website is a website registrar and will be making new child websites.

2) Parent website will have front-end templates to be selected for child website.

3) Each child website will be complete ecommerce website.

4) There will be only one back-end(admin-side) template which will pull specific child websites data using login details (username and email address).

5) Parent Website also has a product search engine which will pull and show the requested product from all the child websites(which ever child has that product in it).

6)Every child website's admin side will have an option to backup their data and download.

Now, I need to know, which one is better decision either I create different databases for each child? Or use same database? also which will be better in performance.

Please give me advice for designing my database and tables.

Thanks a Million in Advance..!

Answer (score 0):

The different `databases` (or schemata) of MySQL can be configured to have different database users with their rights and passwords and the like. So if you intend to give the different webmasters some access to their Website on database level, the easiest way is to create several databases.

For those operations that search through all databases this is a drawback.

The other way would be to have a real complete application and to encapsulate the database completely, but you have to implement whole role system and rights checks and security by your own and make no mistake (SQL injection and the like).

The performance should be no difference at all, you can also join over different databases.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply.. I'm focusing on working on single database now. Though it will take my time and will be difficult as in I'll have to pay more attention to security checks. And yess i'll be carefull that i dont make any mistake..! :) Thanks again.

Comment: You should then give most tables a column client_id, and "row level backup" must be programmed by you via csv/json Download/Upload. It needs some work to have the client separation in the application instead of the database, but it also has much more flexibility. So you have to write more code but get more freedom. Be careful with client separation then, so that one client can not simply modify URL and get other products! Every request needs to make sure the requested "entity" (product, customer etc) is for the right client.

Comment: Yes your suggection is speaking my schema design !! :). and to be honest I have never done row level backup I was thinking to take help for that later but i guess it better if i know before i design my schema completly may be it requires change in my schema design. Do you have any tutorial link or any reference where I can learn that? Or canu guide me for that? With thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

You can use below approach if suits you-

Keep single DB for your production tables.

keep all log tables in different DB, if you need log tables in your project.

separate tables project/site wise by prefix like table name will start prj1_table_name for project 1 and prj2_table_name for project 2.

As per my assumption you want to keep engine as innodb.

So keep innodb_file_per_table on in your configuration file.

**Benefit:**

1. You can avoid duplicity of same kind of data like your each project may have a user table.
2. If you use different db then either you need to insert a user in all DB's or you need to assume one master DB in which you can keep your user table.
3. If you keep your user table different in all DB's for different site/projects and you want to check all users details/count etc. then you have to use union etc.
4. To keep different log database, you can purge easily all data from this DB and also backup will be easy and short as only structure of log db is required.

These are few benefits I mentioned here. Further it will depend on your actual requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I guess I aint getting your point 4 (DATABACKUP) and Yes I'm now focusing on Single DB now as in what I'm making is say it will be like shopify.com but difference is the parent site will also be a e-commerce site and will have search engine which will pull requested product result from all the childs which ever has it. (as defined in my question above about parent and child site) so for searching through all child sites, for me single DB is easier (I don't know if there's any way to search through all DB's).

Comment: One more thing to ask, is there anything like row level data backup? As every childsite can also backup there data and download it, actually I havent faced this need before so bit confused or may be I lack in knowledge regarding it. Thanks again

Comment: what do you mean by row level backup and what you want to achieve by it.